# what happens to the object which is created locally which is referenced by another object which is global

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

```
public class LinkedList {

Node head;
Node n;
int size;

public void insert(int data) {

    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;
    node.next = null;

    if (head==null) {
        head= node;
         n= head;
         size=1;
    }
    else {
        n.next=node;
        size++;
        n=node;

        }
}
```

what happens to the object node when it reaches the end? will it gets destroyed storing a copy of data inside object n or else it will remain as such?

Comment: A special part of the Java runtime called the garbage collector takes care of destroying all objects when they are no longer in use. see https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/the-life-cycle-of-a-java-object/  - The node is no longer in use or accessible

Comment: The purpose of the garbage collector is to allow you to focus on the application logic instead of such questions. The garbage collector will do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no references to an object, it is eligible for garbage collection.

If there is at least one reference to an object from some other object that is itself not eligible for garbage collection, then the first object would not be eligible for garbage collection. This protects against creating A that references B, and B references back to A, but neither one of them is has any references from anywhere else, so both could be garbage collected.

Also, just to clarify, being *eligible* for garbage collection does not mean that an object will actually be garbage collected.

Comment: at first well call ls.insert(2) and 2 will be stored in node.data , and n = node which means n is referring node . after if we call ls.insert(3) 3 will be stored in node.data which means in the last call  n is referring node , so will n.data be changed to 3 ?